# How to setup now index.html?

Tags: node.js, continuous-deployment, serverless, vercel

I am trying to deply my node.js app to [NOW](https://zeit.co/now),

But when i deploy all i see is the root folder with all the files...

I am supposed to have an index.html file, but i dont know where this happens or where i should set this up?

In webpack? in start.js?

Any ideas?

In my project, i have start.js and app.js

So I guess, I should use `start.js` on the now.json config file

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "start.js", "use": "@now/node" },
    { "src": "index.html", "use": "@now/static" }
  ]
}
```

But I get an error and logs like:

> 'The lambda function size (8.98mb) exceeds the configured limit (5mb). You may increase this by supplying maxLambdaSize to the build config'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error, You have to add `maxLambdaSize` to your build config.

```
{
  "name": "Your Project Name",
  "alias": ["yourAliasGoesHere"],
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js", //put your own stuff here
      "use": "@now/node-server",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "10mb" } //right here
    }
  ]
}
```

Increase or decrease the `maxLambdaSize` as needed.